# How do I rewrite this .htaccess file to remove index.php from CodeIgniter and force HTTPS?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is the content of my .htaccess file.

I want to accomplish two things:

1. Remove `index.php` from the CodeIgniter URL;
2. Force all connections through `https://`

HTTPS works fine but `index.php` remains in the URL. How can I fix this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `http` to `https` rule should be at the top of your htaccess file before all internal rewrite rules.

Comment: that means I put the if block at the end, right ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. :)

Comment: This is a useful tool for creating a rewrite rule for your htaccess.  It lets you put in what you want and where you would like it to point and it writes the rule out ... http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/

Comment: it works. Make an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code for CodeIgniter, hope this will help

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]   

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Also from config.php which is in application config folder, you have to remove index.php and set it to blank

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Have you updated config.php or not? You have to remove index.php from $config['index_page']. See my updated answer.

Comment: I hadn't . Now I did.

Comment: it worked with hiccups. CSS files stopped loading. :(

Comment: Check URL of CSS and js, maybe it is loading with index.php.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are removing index.php from your base url after making changes to .htaccess file.